# AppleScript run set of terminal commands without waiting

Tags: macos, bash, shell, terminal, applescript

I'm writing an AppleScript app.  I have a `do shell script` part of my code that looks something like this:

```
unlink file.file; mv file1.file file2.file; sleep 3; open app.app;
```

Anyway, I need this to run without interrupting the script and without opening a terminal window.  I already know about the `> /dev/null 2>&1 &` thing, but that won't work for me because I need to run these all in sequence, and I couldn't get it to work with multiple commands like that.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you just do the above directly with AppleScript - it doesn't appear that there is any need for this part to be a shell script ?

Answer (score 0):

You can run the entire list of commands as a group:

```
{ unlink file.file; mv file1.file file2.file; sleep 3; open app.app; } >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```